# C#. How to test method that are in same class that I am trying to test

Tags: c#, moq, .net-core-3.1, autofixture

I have methods in my class `CustomerServices` that I need to mock and test. I am not sure If I am mocking correctly? In debugging when code hit `customerService.Object.ProcessCustomer()` then it do not call actual method.

If the methods are calling from other class I know how to mock by using DI and reference object in contractor but I not getting how I can mock method that exist in same class that I am trying to test??

I am using mock and autoFixture

Customer

```
public class Customer
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

Interface

```
public interface ICustomerServices
{
    List<Customer> GetCustomers();
    int ProcessCustomer();
}
```

CustomerService

```
public class CustomerServices : ICustomerServices
{
    public CustomerServices()
    {

    }

    public int ProcessCustomer()
    {
        var customerList = GetCustomers();

        Console.WriteLine($"Total Customer Count {customerList.Count()}");

        return customerList.Count();
    }

    public List<Customer> GetCustomers()
    {
        return new List<Customer>();
    }
}
```

`Test`

```
public class Tests
{
    private readonly Mock<ICustomerServices> customerService;

    public Tests()
    {
        customerService = new Mock<ICustomerServices>();
    }

    [SetUp]
    public void Setup()
    {
    }

    [Test]
    public void Test1()
    {
        //Arrange 
        var fixture = new Fixture();

        var customerMoq = fixture.CreateMany<Customer>(5);
        customerService.Setup(_ => _.GetCustomers()).Returns((System.Collections.Generic.List<Customer>)customerMoq);

        //Act
        var actualResult = customerService.Object.ProcessCustomer();

        //Assert
    }
}
```

Comment: "that I need to mock and test" - hang on... let's asses our priors here. Who is saying you _need_ to mock and test this in the first place?

Comment: By testing `ProcessCustomer`, all you are doing is testing if `List<T>.Count()` works as expected, basically. Given, that you also test `GetCustomers` to return an expected amount of entities. - So, that doesn't make too much sense.

Comment: what I want to test is complex and I simplify an example. My question how to mock method that are in same class that I am testing

Comment: If you mock parts of the class that is under test you no longer testing that class but something else. If that is somehow needed (i can only think of an abstract class you want to test where this makes sense)  come up with a better example.

Answer (score 0):

You should not mock the service that is being tested.

Your test should look more like this:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestGetUser()
{
    var mockLogger = new Mock<ILogger>(MockBehaviour.Strict);
    var mockSomeOtherDependency = new Mock<IA>(MockBehaviour.Strict);

    var beingTested = new UsersService(
        logger: mockLogger.Object
        someOtherDependency: mockSomeOtherDependency.Object,
        ...);

    mockSomeOtherDependency.Setup( r => r.GetCustomer("test")).Returns( new Customer(...));

    var r = beingTested.ProcessCustomer(); 

    Assert.IsNotNull(r);
}
```